# Jprofiler latest products and features compatible with azure

Tags: jprofiler

Is jprofiler current version and other new ej technologies new products can be used for profiling and monitoring azure,  AWS?

Answer (score 0):

JProfiler profiles JVMs. Whether it can profile a particular JVM depends on the architecture and the version of the JVM, but not on the cloud service where the JVM is running.

For a current list of supported platforms and JVMs, see

https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/featuresPlatforms.html